# In Windows Form Combobox Default value

Tags: c#, windows

I’m creating a `Combobox` in Windows Form Application I Want value "Select" at 0th index how can I do it? I've tried

```
 cbxWeigtType Item = new cbxWeigtType();
 Item.Text = "my string";
 this.DropDownList1.SelectedItem = Item;
```

Comment: do you want to select the value of first item  or set default select of your combobox to first item?

Comment: Sir I Want to Set default Select

Answer (score 5):

You can do this:

```
comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, "Select");
comboBox1.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Insert at 0th index and then set it as `selectedIndex`.

Comment: Thanks Sir It Working properly

Comment: Sir its working when combobox is empty but if combox is bind with datasource then it not working because i want to add "Select" at 0th index while combobox is bindded with data source

Comment: Sir it show following error    ({"Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set."})

Comment: When you are setting the datasouce and after that trying to add new item, it won't allow to do that, there are two solutions in this regards, either add this selected item within your DB so whenever list will be binded to combobox, the item will also be there. Another solution could be, instead of setting datasouce, add items to the combobox one by one which isn't a recommended way.

Comment: Sir I Found the solution using key value pair answer is given

Answer (score 0):

```
private void BindComboBoxItem()
{
    ItemRepository repo = new ItemRepository();
    List<Item> items = repo.GetAll();
    List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> allitems = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
    KeyValuePair<int, string> first = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(0, "Please Select");
    allitems.Add(first);
    foreach (Item item in items)
    {
        KeyValuePair<int, string> obj = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(item.Id, item.Name);
        allitems.Add(obj);
    }
    cbxSelectItem.DataSource = allitems;
    cbxSelectItem.DisplayMember = "Value";
    cbxSelectItem.ValueMember = "Key";
}
```